# how to turn into this json to kotlin class?

Tags: json, kotlin, retrofit

Does anyone know the ***kotlin classes*** of this `JSON`?
I want to use it for my app, but it is complicated.

Additionally, I have not worked with this type of kotlin, I have only worked with simple `JSON`.

I need to understand this before I complete my `apiService`

```json
{
  "id": 1044,
  "name": "shoes",
  "type": "simple",
  "price": "16000",
  "weight": "",
  "dimensions": {
    "length": "",
    "width": "",
    "height": ""
  },
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 62,
      "name": "orthopedy",
      "slug": "orthopedic"
    },
    {
      "id": 60,
      "name": "medicine",
      "slug": "medical-equipments"
    },
    {
      "id": 63,
      "name": "sockss",
      "slug": "socks"
    }
  ],
  "tags": [],
  "images": [
    {
      "id": 862,
      "date_created": "2019-01-18T19:37:27",
      "date_created_gmt": "2019-01-18T21:37:27",
      "date_modified": "2019-01-18T19:37:27",
      "date_modified_gmt": "2019-01-18T21:37:27",
      "src": "https://www.davadoctor.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/davadoctort_arm.png",
      "name": "davadoctort_arm",
      "alt": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 918,
      "date_created": "2019-01-20T11:09:39",
      "date_created_gmt": "2019-01-20T13:09:39",
      "date_modified": "2019-01-20T11:09:39",
      "date_modified_gmt": "2019-01-20T13:09:39",
      "src": "https://www.davadoctor.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/cropped-davadoctort_arm.png",
      "name": "cropped-davadoctort_arm.png",
      "alt": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to figure out where this `JSON` goes, where I put the ***question mark***:

```
private const val BASE_URL = "***?????***"
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
interface davaApiService{
    @GET(***"???"***)
    suspend fun getProperties(): List<***????***>
}
object davaApi{
    val retrofitSerive : davaApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(davaApiService::class.java) }
}
```

Comment: If you've use simple JSON before I would simplify this example JSON until you can do it, and then start adding the more complicated bits. Once you've reach a concreate problem like "how do I add the categories array", post what you have  and what the specific problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin in intelliJ called json to kotlin class converter. It will create the appropriate classes for your JSON. See the documentation here:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-